# Повторная отправка и получение данных ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Есть вот такой код:

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e){
    $("#div1").load( 
        $('#form1').attr('action'),
        {a: $('#form1 input[name="a"]').val()},
        function(){
            $("#div1").hide();
        $("#div1").show(2000);
        }
    );
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

Как сделать так, чтобы при повторной отправке формы данные обновлялись?
```

Comment: данные в чем?

Answer (score 1):

Перед функцией добавьте:

```
var flag=0;
```

В свою функцию добавьте вначале:

```
if(flag!=0){$('#твой_блок').load('url')}
```

и в конце исполнения функции припишите 
`flag=1`

Работает так. При первом исполнении функции флажку flag присваиваем значение 1 и исполняем её. При повторной отправке в блок 'твой блок' загрузится страница с адреса 'url'.